# Eclipse JPA: Unable to delete Table associations (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, jpa

Trying to work through the wizard `Generate Custom Entities` in Eclipse ("JPA Entities from Tables"), Eclipse proposes some table associations to generate.

In fact, I cannot delete them in the dialog "Table associations". If one of them is selected, the remove button is greyed out and there's no way to activate it.

Does anybody know when this happens and how to solve it?
Where does eclipse have these associations from?

First, I thought it has to be this way when the database backend has foreign keys and associations defined (using SQL Server). But this cannot be the reason. If it was, other associations would show up as well.

I don't know whether it's related to the database type SQL Server, but I think it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have defined a [connection profile](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user/doc/html/asc1229700344899.html?cp=17_5_0) and there is an active connection with the underlying database, the **Table associations** view shows existing associations between SQL tables.

Button [image: delete association button] is disabled by default and this is expected. It becomes active when you add a new association by clicking [image: new association button] button, so you can only delete associations you already created (not those who already exist in the database).

Anyway you can delete the existing associations by:

- clicking on a given association in the **Table associations** view
- unselecting **Generate this association** checkbox below

Deleting these associations will entail ONLY (re)creation of the entity model (now without the already deleted relationships) but NOT the database schema itself.

Comment: Thank you. The strange thing is: I'm pretty sure that there are more associations existing in the database than it shows me. But I did it differently. cheers.